# Adding multiple fonts to UIAppFonts overrides each other

Tags: iphone, uifont

I'm trying to add some custom fonts to an iPhone app through `UIAppFonts` in `Info.plist`.

I can reach both fontnames by code, i.e. `MyFont-Bold` and `MyFont-Medium`.

My problem is that the last font in `UIAppFonts` array overrides the other one, making both `MyFont-Bold` and `MyFont-Medium` render out `MyFont-Bold` if this is the last entry in the plist array. By dragging `MyFont-Bold` as the first entry makes both font-names render MyFont-Medium.

The property list excerpt:

```
UIAppFonts
  item 0    MyFont-Medium
  item 1    MyFont-Bold
```

I'm calling the font with:

```
UIFont* applicationFontBold = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont-Bold"
                                              size:[UIFont buttonFontSize]];

UIFont* applicationFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont-Medium"
                                          size:[UIFont buttonFontSize]];
```

Anyone tried adding multiple fonts to one font-family?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if it was ever fixed, but I worked around this issue by actually modifying the font family names inside the .ttf files, using vim editor. Because you have different font-types (Bold and Medium) but actually the same fontfamily (MyFont) - the system mixes them up.  So what I did in the first file - I actually modified the family to be MyFontA, and in the second file MyFontB (of course I had different names - these are just to match the example above).
This worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with multiple fonts of the same font family. I found that if I viewed the info.plist file as source code, the xml not formatted properly which cause only some of the fonts to register.